# Not able to scroll pdf after zooming in JoanZapata android library

Tags: android, pdf

I am new to android. I am using JoanZapata android library to view pdf inside my app. Everything is working fine, but after zooming I am not able to scroll pages.

What could be causing this?

If you know please suggest me any other library.

I have checked Android barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer its very lengthy(20mb)
     **UPDATE:**
       java code where I display the pdf

```
 public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        PDFView pdfView;
      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
            pdfView= (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
       File pdfFile = new File(getCacheDir(),RecyclerViewAdapter.name);  
      pdfView.fromFile(pdfFile).swipeVertical(true).load(); }}
```

//  my xml code looks like this

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <com.joanzapata.pdfview.PDFView
            android:id="@+id/pdfView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: does it not scroll pages after you zoom out all the way again?

Comment: If I zoom it will scroll.But I need to scroll when the pdf is zoomed.

Comment: update your question with the code where the pdf is displayed. That should help people understand what is going on